# How to check if an element exists within an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to check if an array within an object contains an element `userAnswer` or not. Is there a good way to do this using es6. I've tried a few however, I can't seem to get it to work properly. Most of my attempts return an error. Any help would be appreciated.

**Last Attempt**

`conductedExam.questions.some(question => question.userAnswer.includes(Object))`

**Data**

```
{
  _id: '1',
  questions: [
    { name: '1', userAnswer: 'one' },
    { name: '2', userAnswer: 'two' },
    { name: '2' }
  ]
};
```

Comment: What is the `Object` that you're passing to the `.includes`? Is that an actual object, or a string like `'one'`, or what? Not entirely sure what the logic you're looking for is

Comment: Sorry, this might be my noob problem. I thought `Object` meant to check if any object exists. Is that possible or am I not looking at this correctly.

Comment: Because no object exists at any of the `userAnswer`s in the given input, would you want the output to be `false` here? (you only have strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasOwnProperty`:

```js
const conductedExam = {
  _id: '1',
  questions: [
    { name: '1', userAnswer: 'one' },
    { name: '2', userAnswer: 'two' },
    { name: '2' }
  ]
};

console.log(conductedExam.questions.some(e => !e.hasOwnProperty("userAnswer")));
```

Comment: I want it to return true if it doesn't exist and false if it does exists

Comment: Oh, right - fixed @bp123. Does that work for you now?

Comment: @bp123 It still returns `true` because one element in the array *doesn't* have the property. Do you want to return `false` if *all* elements have the property and `true` if *no* elements have the property?

Answer (score 0):

Using `hasOwnProperty` might work.

`conductedExam.questions.some(question => question.hasOwnProperty('userAnswer'))` returns true